# Make a gmap view embeddable on another site

Tags: 7, views, google-maps, nodes

The website I'm building has a google map view. I want to provide a code snippet to site visitors to let them embed this gmap view on their own site. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this in D7?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622728/embed-a-drupal-gmap-view-on-other-sites) over at the SO main site, but it appears to be D6-specific since Embed Widgets doesn't have a D7 release and Web Widgets only has an abandoned D7 release. So I'm wondering if there's another way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own iframe: http://www.iframehtml.com/

You will most likely want to create custom page output so that you aren't including extra regions from your site. You can do so by creating a [custom html.tpl.php template](http://drupal.org/node/1041768#comment-4011104) (might not be necessary) and page template for the map.